# C++ For Loops, Asterisk Inverted Triangle

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, char

I need your help.
I need to write a program that has four asterisk triangles, one on top of the other. I am having a difficulty with the third triangle. An inverted triangle with ten rows that should display like this:

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

Can anyone help me?

```
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
   cout << "\nAsterisk Triangluar Patterns:\n";
   cout << "\nPattern (a).\n\n";
   int i,j,rows;
   int ROWS = 10;
   //initiates the max limit of rows and/ columns the triangle may have 
   int k = 11;

    for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }
    cout << "\nPattern (b).\n\n";
    for (i = 10; i >= 1; i = i-1)
    {
    // begin second loop from 1 to i
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j = j+1)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
    }         

    cout << "\nPattern (c).\n\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout <<"*";
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nPattern (d).\n\n";
    for (i=1;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    cout << "*";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }


    cin.get();

    cin.get();

        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Well, what's your idea about how to do it (you already mentioned `for` loop)? You should also have some basic stuff covered in your textbook.

Comment: Xcode has nothing to do with this, nor does an inverted index. And a search of this site for "[cpp] inverted triangle" will yield *dozens* of questions if you want to pilfer someone else's code. You'd be doing yourself a disservice, however, if you don't at least *try* to do it yourself *first*, and if you run into problems, post *your* code here and maybe we can help.

Comment: @Cyber_Lo  What are these four triangles? Show them.

Comment: Here is my code _WhozCraig

Comment: @Cyber_Lo:  review your comments, as the code is difficult at best to read in a comment.  **EDIT YOUR POST** with the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to do the task.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( i + 1 ) << std::setfill( ' ' ) << '*' 
                  << std::setw( N - i ) << std::setfill( '*' ) << '\n';
    }        
}
```

The program output is

```
**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *
```

Or by means of standard algorithms

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        auto out = std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout );
        *std::fill_n( std::fill_n( out, i, ' ' ), N - i, '*' ) = '\n';
    }            
}
```

The output will be the same as shown above.

In fact what you need is to write three loops: one outer loop and two inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way I can think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

   for ( int i = 10; i >= 0; --i )
       std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(10) << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl;
       // or std::cout << std::string(10 - i, ' ') << std::string(i, '*') << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

However, if this confuses you. You can do it this way:

```
for ( int i = 10; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j++ ) cout << " ";
    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) cout << "*";
    cout << endl;
}
```

which is closer to your code.